# Accessing that object's variables

Tags: scala

I am trying to write an object comparison script in scala. It just need to compare two object's variables of the same type

```
class Student (name : String) {

  def nameEquals (that : Student) = {
    that match {
      case that : Student => this.name == that.name (throws error)
    }
  }
}
```

Why cannot I access that's variables even though we know it's type?

Comment: Can you also paste the structure of Student class ? like all the attributes ?

Comment: @zenwraight, this is it. Student has only one attribute. It is name

Comment: btw, the match is unnecessary because you already have the type in the argument

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just define name like val:

```
class Student (val name : String)
```

Comment: Ah thank you, that is because no accessors and mutators are created for this one.

Answer (score 0):

You can both define your attribute as val or define your class as a case class which will apply the val by default. Both will work fine.

```
case class Student (name : String)

class Student (val name : String)
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens, because when you declare `class Student(name: String)`, you only declare the member `name`, which is private and inaccessible to other objects.

For `Student.name` to be accessible from outside, you need a getter for it. You can declare the `Student` class like this:

```
class Student(val name: String) {
  def nameEquals(that: Student) = this.name == that.name
}
```

Declaring `name` as a `val` creates a getter method of the same name for a private member `val` under the hood. If you want a setter for this member, as well (usually, though, immutability is preferred), you can declare `name` as a `var`, and it lets you assign a value to `name`.

You could also skip the `val` if you used a `case class` instead, like this:

```
case class Student(name: String) {
  def nameEquals(that: Student) = this.name == that.name
}
```

That is, because a `case class` provides getter methods for the member values by default, as well as some other common methods for simple data classes, for example, even an equality method, which might suit you in this specific case, for exapmple, simply using this:

```
case class Student(name: String)
```

would let you compare two students like this: `Student("John Doe") == Student("John Doe")` and `Student("Jane Doe") != Student("John Doe")`, which both evaluate as `true`, which might be exactly what you would like to do here.

Also, by the way, that pattern matching clause is unnecessary in your `nameEquals` method, as the `that` case is the only possible case (other than `null` as a parameter).

Comment: Thank you, it was great explanation